# "Coming in this country" or "coming into this country"

Tags: idioms, prepositions, north-american-english

Is it correct to say *coming **in** this country* just as it is with *coming **into** this country* ?

There's no doubt in my mind that I can use both with *arrive*:  *arriving **in** this country* vs. *arriving **into** this country*.

But somehow the context of directionality, rather than location, of **in** with other verbs, such as *come*, isn't as clear-cut to me. I feel that *in* is more of a location with other verbs rather than directionality. If so, directionality needs to be specifically reinforced with *into*. Or, is *in* always acceptable in both contexts, regardless of verb, such as *come, run, travel, arrive, step, walk*, etc.?

Update: Weirdly, I also feel that if the meaning is ambiguous, it can be clarified in speech by emphasizing *in*. If I saw the phrase *I ran in the house* in print my first interpretation would be location, but if I vocally emphasized *I ran **in** the house* (with some kind of pause or tone change) I'd be partially able to convey directionality.

Note: I'm in the United States, this is a US question.

Answer (score 0):

The validity of "in" is very contextual. As you correctly pointed out, "arriving in this country" is grammatical. So is "arriving into this country". However, "in" doesn't always mean "into" for all verbs.

Let me explain. A preposition depends on the type of question that may be asked to justify the use of that preposition. If you ask "where to?", for instance, the answer will usually involve "into" (if the type of phrase involves moving to a position where you are "within" something). For instance: where are you going [to]? I am going into the cinema.

On the other hand, if the question is "where", as in "where are you?", then if you are within a place, the preposition will usually be "in". For instance: "Where is that boy hiding? He is hiding **in** the bedroom."

By finding the type of question most appropriate, one can find the verbs which need "in", the ones which need "into", and the ones that need both if the verb can answer both "where to" and "where".

For instance, the verb "arrive" answers "where" (where did you arrive?) and "where to" (where did you arrive "to"), thus "in" and "into" can both be used.

The verb "walk" answers "where to" (A tall woman walked into the small house), as well as "where" (where is the action being done? The family walks in Switzerland means that the family is walking within Switzerland).

Indeed, "in" is valid for a lot of movement verbs; you can see that by replacing "in" with "within", for instance. However, "in" does not necessarily give the sense of directionality, so the answer is no; in the general case, "in" really indicates the position where the action is being done. "Arriving" is slightly different, and as "coming" is rather similar to "arriving" in terms of the questions that can be asked to derive it, you can use "in" and "into" interchangeably with "coming". However, as seen above, this isn't the case for all verbs.

Comment: Yeah, my gut feel is that if the verb strongly implies directionality already, such as *come/arrive*, then *in* is sufficient. But otherwise, verbs like *walk/run* do not imply directionality by themselves. In those cases *into* is required.

Comment: But I still feel I could say *I walked in the store* for directionality, and I could also say *I stepped in it* for directionality. Maybe I could even say *I ran in the house* with that meaning. It's ambiguous, but especially with some kind of voice modulation (like emphasizing the "in"), I guess I could clarify the meaning.

Comment: BTW you can delete the stuff  about German. German has cases where the following noun will be clearly inflected to indicate one or the other, so you'll never confuse an accusative with a dative, which is how this distinction is made. In English it's much more subtle without cases.

Comment: "I walked in the store" means you are located inside the store and are walking around there. But that's not the way you'd say it, you'd normally say "I walked inside the store"

Comment: @Mitch I'd argue that *I walked inside the store* could also imply direction.

Comment: @geneb. Done, replaced with an explanation solely in English.